# How to upgrade Debian 11 to Debian 12?

Tags: debian, apt

This question might sound very simple, but I can't find the command to upgrade my Debian 11 to 12.

I tried `apt update` and `apt upgrade` and `apt dist-upgrade` and `apt full-upgrade` and what not.

None of them changes the version. After each I use `cat /etc/os-release` and I see 11 (bullseye).

How can I upgrade to Debian 12 (bookworm)?

Answer (score 6):

The release notes for every release of Debian explain how to upgrade from the previous release; [here are the instruction for upgrading for Debian 11 to 12 on `amd64`](https://www.debian.org/releases/bookworm/amd64/release-notes/ch-upgrading.en.html).

The short version, assuming you haven’t added third-party repositories, is:

- ensure your Debian 11 system is fully updated (`sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`)
- replace `bullseye` with `bookworm` in `/etc/apt/sources.list`
- [add `non-free-firmware` if necessary](https://www.debian.org/releases/bookworm/amd64/release-notes/ch-information.en.html#non-free-split)
- update your repository caches (`sudo apt update`)
- run a minimal upgrade (`sudo apt upgrade --without-new-pkgs`)
- run a full upgrade (`sudo apt full-upgrade`)

In any case you should really read the release notes.

Comment: So, the whole secret is in changing the source. I was searching for that and I couldn't find it. Thank you so much.

Comment: You really should read the update instructions in the release notes every time you upgrade to a release that is new to you: sometimes there will be special steps you'll need to follow if your system is configured in a particular way. Debian tries very hard to avoid such special cases, but sometimes they are unavoidable.